# How to run sh script in lxterminal using double click on Raspbian

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, raspberry-pi

I've read so many threads regarding running a script using double click, but none of the ways describes my case.
My operating system is Raspbian Bookworm (Debian), the graphical shell is LXDE and the terminal is lxterminal.
In short, I have a command that I need to run in a terminal window, and I would like the entire command with the ability to run it to be contained in a single file.

My command is:

```
"sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/mmcblk0 | pv -s 15986589696 | zstd -2 -qfo /media/pi/3F1E75657ACEB065/backupRPI-$(date +%%Y-%%m-%%d_%%H-%%M-%%S).img.zst"
```

How can I run this by double clicking? I tried a lot of combinations and still doesn't works.

Comment: (1) "I tried a lot of combinations and still doesn't work" – What exactly did you try? In what way these don't work? Any error messages? Have you tried to create a `something.desktop` file? (2) The double-quotes seem wrong. Only without them the command makes sense. In some applications one needs to quote *the* command, so *maybe* the quotes are leftovers from some of your tries. Please review: do the quotes belong to the actual command you want to run? I don't think so.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks for reply, now it works after some combinations.
I did this in desktop file: `lxterminal --command "sudo /usr/bin/dd bs=4M if=/dev/mmcblk0 | /usr/bin/pv -s 15986589696 | zstd -2 -qfo /media/pi/3F1E75657ACEB065/backupRPI-$(date +%%Y-%%m-%%d_%%H-%%M-%%S).img.zst"`.
And yea, the quotes are important because without guotes the name of file is not generated correctly (not has the date) :)

Comment: (3) Well, this only means the quotes belong to the command that starts with `lxterminal`. But your question does not state this command, it states the command (pipeline) that starts with `sudo`. This command does not need these quotes, they make it fail. (4) Please do not expand/clarify in comments. Take our short [tour] to learn how the site is designed to work. Improve your question by [edit]ing it. (5) "now it works after some combinations" – Consider [writing an answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) then.